# Sql Group By with Max equivalent in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, google-spreadsheets

My excel sheet has this data as an example:

```
type   |make    |price
--------------------
cars   |honda   |500
cars   |acura   |600
cars   |ford    |550
trucks |toyota  |350
trucks |ford    |475
trucks |chevy   |400
```

I can use a pivot table to group by type and make, and get max of the price, but what I really want is to get the max of the price, and then the single record make associated with that max value, so that the data will ultimately look like:

```
type   |make    |max of price
--------------------
cars   |acura   |600
trucks |ford    |475
```

I can easily do this query in sql against a database, but am not finding the correct way to do this in excel.

Answer (score 3):

Use `FILTER` to get the right rows:

```
=FILTER($A$2:$C$7,MAXIFS($C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7)=$C$2:$C$7)
```

The first parameter is the data range you want to filter. The second parameter is the condition. So, max price by type is equal to the current row price.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Power Query.

- Group on the `type` without aggregating.
- Then add two custom columns to return the `make` and `price` associated with the max price for each resultant table (group).

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="vehicles"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"type"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [type=nullable text, make=nullable text, price=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "make", each Record.Field(Table.Max([Grouped],"price"),"make")),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "price", each Record.Field(Table.Max([Grouped],"price"),"price")),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"make", type text}, {"price", Currency.Type}, {"type", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Grouped"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]